# I need to split two different dataframes sequentially into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, divide

I need to split two different dataframes sequentially in python

dataframe 1

```
date        coefficient 
2020-10-14  4.0
2019-08-06  8.0
2017-09-05  8.0
```

dataframe 2

```
date        bases
2020-12-30  6498927
```

i need to divide each bases by coefficient sequentially
like this

```
date        split base  
2020-10-14  1624731
2019-08-06  203091
2017-09-05  25386
```

if you can help me I appreciate it

Comment: `((1/df1['coefficient']).cumprod() * df2['bases'].iloc[0]).astype(int)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples. ...  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df1['split base'] = ((1/df1['coefficient']).cumprod() * df2['bases'].iloc[0]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
         date  coefficient  split base
0  2020-10-14          4.0     1624731
1  2019-08-06          8.0      203091
2  2017-09-05          8.0       25386
```

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=((1/df1['coefficient']).cumprod() * df2['bases'].iloc[0]).astype(int) very grateful